# Python: write to file multiple times without open/close for each write

Tags: python, file

How can i open file in python and write to it multiple times?

I am using speech recognition, and i want one file to change its contents based on what i say.
Other application needs to be able to read this file.
Is there way to do this, or i need to open/close for each write?

Comment: How does the "other application" know you're done talking?  What triggers it to read this file?

Comment: It doesnt, i am using voice recognition with games, so i send keypress to application (wolfenstein:enemy territory) and that keypress executes contents of file in question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just keep the file object around and write to it whenever you want. You might need to [`flush`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) it after each write to make things visible to the outside world.

If you do the writes from a different process, just open the file in append mode ("a").

Answer (score 7):

```
f = open('myfile.txt','w')
f.write('Hi')
f.write('Hi again!')
f.write('Is this thing on?')
# do this as long as you need to
f.seek(0,0) # return to the beginning of the file if you need to
f.close() # close the file handle
```

Comment: Possibly need an `f.seek(0,0)` to rewind back to the beginning.

Comment: How about a flush each time? This should not hurt the performance when the input is so slow.

Comment: Never depend on calling `close` explicitly. **Always** use a context manager (`with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f`).

Comment: Never say, "never say never."

Comment: `def never(say): return never(say)`

Comment: nevertheless never say never